# How do I use android Emoji2 emoji picker in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, emoji

Android seems to provide no documentation whatsoever to using its Emoji2 emoji-picker : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/emoji2

Does anyone have any experience with using it in jetpack compose?

Comment: Compose supports [any kind of view](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose). What makes you think the EmojiPicker is any different in that regard?

Comment: You might have commented on the wrong question. This is asking about how to use the emoji2 emoji picker in jetpack compose, because it has no documentation.

Comment: Nope, I commented on the right question. What makes you think the Emoji2 Emoji Picker is any different from any other View? They are all supported in Compose.

Comment: Do you have experience with using the emoji 2 emoji picker? How does one use it? Where are the docs for how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dependency (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/emoji2/emojipicker/package-summary)

```
implementation 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-emojipicker:1.4.0-beta05'
```

And then add it in compose with:

```
@Composable
fun EmojiPicker() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            EmojiPickerView(context)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}
```

(From https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose)

Comment: This works really bad with scrollable components such as ModalBottomSheet for example. I would suggest using this library (or implement a fetcher yourself) to fetch the emojis from the network and then display them however you want https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/emoji-core